# Which type of convergent boundary creates the tallest mountains?

Tags: geology, geophysics, plate-tectonics, structural-geology, mountain-building

Which type of convergent boundary creates the tallest mountains?

- Continental-Continental
- Ocean-Ocean
- Ocean-Continental

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  homework questions are expected to show effort to answer the question prior to posting.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?lq=1) You can [edit] your question with this so people will answer it.

Answer (score 2):

The type of convergent boundaries is not the only factor. From the current configuration of the world one could be tempted to say that Continental-Continental collisions would form the tallest mountains. And they are indeed the most dramatic tectonic collisions and they formed the Himalayas, that are almost 2,000 m taller than any other mountain on Earth. However, the india-Asia collision wasn't any collision it was the most dramatic collision in a long time with convergence rates of [16 cm/year](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2010JB008051/full), way more than any current convergence rate.
[image]
From [USGS](https://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/dynamic/himalaya.html)

Therefore, the convergence rate is also a very important factor. The tallest mountain outside the Himalayas is mount Aconcagua in an oceanic-continental boundary. With a convergence rate of about 6 cm/year, and that have been [below 16 cm/year at least for the last 22 million years](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227232445_Subduction_Erosion_-_the_Normal_Mode_of_Fore-Arc_Material_Transfer_along_the_Chilean_Margin/figures?lo=1).
So it is difficult to say how tall would be Mount Aconcagua if you speed up the convergence rate between Nazca and South America plates by 260%.

I don't think there is a definite answer to your question, unless you constrain other factors, like convergence rate, plates thicknesses, etc.